# Reset TPM system on 2005 Toyota Corolla

Tags: toyota, corolla, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

Recently, my daughter told me the tire pressure monitor (TPM) light had come on in our 2005 Toyota Corolla (USA model). We checked the tires and found that one was indeed a bit low, and we brought it up to pressure. The TPM light remained on, so I assumed there must be a defective sending unit, but when I picked up the car, the guy at the shop said there was nothing wrong, and that the TPM light just needed to be reset. (Our 2010 Toyota RAV4 doesn't behave this way.) Does anyone know the procedure for resetting the light after correcting the tire pressure problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It's exactly the same with my Toyota Yaris Hybrid 2017 European model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure all tires are at the specified pressure.

Locate the tire pressure monitor reset button

[image]

Switch the key to the off position, turn the key to the on position and hold the TPMS reset button until the light shuts off.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer to an RTFM question. I've now got a note in the back of my owner's manual with the correct page number.